# What is similar to LSQUnivariateSpline in C#

Tags: c#, python, spline

I have one project in python and I want to convert into C#.
I don't know anything about Python.
So can you guys tell me, What is LSQUnivariateSpline and How can I implement similar thing in c#?

Comment: _What is LSQUnivariateSpline_ - it's a [One-dimensional spline with explicit internal knots.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline.html). Presumably if you're using it you know what that means, because I don't!

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/3526685#file-interpolator-cs) might help

Comment: @stuartd, Thank you very much for your reply. The given link is broken so could you please re-share the link?

Comment: Which link? The scipy and the gist link both work for me here.

Comment: Sorry. Same link was not working for me yesterday. Today its working fine. Thank you very much.